# Gremlin query for Cosmos Graph DB to get the graph structure surrounding a single vertex, filtering out nodes with specific labels

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin

I am working with the Gremlin API to query a Cosmos Graph DB. I currently have a query that will return the graph structure surrounding a single vertex:

```
g.V('VERTEX_ID').repeat(__.outE().simplePath().subgraph('subGraph').inV()).until(__.outE().count().is(eq(0))).cap('subGraph')
```

I'm looking to add some filtering capability to exclude nodes with a certain property or label. Is this something that is possible? Attempting to avoid implementing the filtering with the resulting sub graph myself!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to exclude the vertices in your subgraph but still follow their incident edges..? In that case, you'd make the subgraph step optional (depend on your filter criteria).

```
g.V('VERTEX_ID').
  repeat(__.outE().simplePath().sideEffect(
           __.not(__.bothV().hasLabel('foobar')).
              not(__.bothV().has('foo','bar')).
              subgraph('subGraph')).inV()).
    until(__.not(__.outE())).
  cap('subGraph')
```

The query above will follow all edges, but only include those in the subgraph that are not incident to a vertex with a `foobar` label or a `foo` property with the value `bar`.

Comment: This seems to end the traversal once it reaches a node that meets the criteria specified on either line 4 or 5. For example, if every single one of the start node's neighbours had the property 'colour' set to 'red', the query would return nothing even if there were nodes beyond the red nodes that had a different 'colour' property.